# how to load image from URL in gridview with json data ?(categories and subcategories)

Tags: java, android, json

Json code URL: http://www.vnsupa.com/dulieujson/data.json so how i get image from that url. i don't know build loop to get JSONAraay and JSON Object

Comment: what url to get image, or can you share the documentation of that api?

Comment: You should try to implement it by yourself first. Then come back here with your codes in case you can not overcome the issue. There are a lot of instructions for Json parser in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are quite new to android dev, below are libraries to help you achieve you're goal.

1. Make sure your json contains the correct image url, for example like this https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/3493/3571/products/E07154B5-E751-438F-8CEB-D403E599F9F2_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1567053731
2. Use [retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make network request, together with [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) you can create a models matching the response from your server.
3. Lastly use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the url into your ImageView.

Those are the common standard libraries that will satisfy your requirements, ofcourse there are other alternative like [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).